# How can I realize following custom option constellation?

Tags: product, configurable-product, custom-options, rwd

At the moment I'm creating all my products over custom options.

Let's say I got 2 **main** - custom options for my product(Choose between standard model and custom model):

A - standard (colour, length.. is already configured)

B - custom -> The customer can decide which colour and length he wants to have.

So If customer picks option A - he doesn't need to care about the other option and if he picks option B he doesn't need to care about A. The point is, that B needs "Required Fields" so he must always check option B wherever he wants it or not. Of course you could just set the fields to non-required but that's not the way I want to go. Maybe he can get the choice to choose between those first main options first before he(if he chooses B) can chooses the custom option. And yes I could also create two products but that's not what I want.

[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento doesn'T support this our of the box. So you need a module or write your own.

I used *Pektsekeye - Dependent Custom Options* once which worked fine.

Comment: I checked the extension - this should work.